# Does running a tor hidden service require a relay?

Tags: onion-services

I want to know if running a tor hidden service also creates a relay/node. I want to know this because my vps provider bans tor nodes.

Comment: No. A hidden service is not a relay and running a relay and hidden service on the same tor instance, or even server, is not recommended.

Comment: (I can't beleive this isn't a duplicate?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, running a hidden service requires very little, not even an open port, you can do it with purely outbound requests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally, but it's not a requirement. You better have 1-2-3 **different** relays running 24/7/365 to use as a bridge or entries for your HS host - it will improve it's visibility and speed greatly. Strictly and minimalistically speaking - no, just an instance of Tor able to connect to the network is minimal-enough.

Answer (score 0):

Single word answer for your question: no.